# A required parameter "client_secret" is missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a website in JavaSpring I use Spring Security to log in to the application I implemented via LinkedIn. When logging in I get this error (http://localhost:8080/login?error=[invalid_request]%20A%20required%20parameter%20%20%22client_secret%22%20is%20missing) I can't figure out how to solve it I'm 100% sure I specified it correctly in settings (spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-secret)
Please tell me how to solve this problem

application.properties file:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-id=****
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-secret=****
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.scope=profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/linkedin
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-name=LinkedIn
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.provider=linkedin
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-authentication-method=post
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.authorization-uri=https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.token-uri=https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.user-info-uri=https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.jwk-set-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.user-name-attribute=id
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.user-info-authentication-method=post
```

class SpringSecurityConfig:

```
/*..other code..*/
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                            .requestMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                            .loginPage("/login")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                            .failureHandler(new OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler())
                            .successHandler(oAuth2LoginSuccessHandler)
                            .permitAll()
                    )
/*..other code..*/
```

I tried recreating the new application in linked develops, but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Change client-authentication-method=post to client_authentication_method: client_secret_post

the post is not supported anymore

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).